# paste: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, process-substitution, msys

I'm new to Unix command. I was trying to execute the following commands in Git Bash and it directs to error message: paste: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory

```
# Set Up Image Lists
paste <(awk "{print \"$PWD\"}" <5k.part) 5k.part | tr -d '\t' > 5k.txt
paste <(awk "{print \"$PWD\"}" <trainvalno5k.part) trainvalno5k.part | tr -d '\t' > trainvalno5k.txt
```

Could anyone help me understand what it means and what I should do?

Comment: If this is Git Bash, you're not actually on Linux, are you? On Windows, right?

Comment: @muru Yes I'm on Windows. Somehow I need to run Linux commands on it.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the files for `cat` by _process substitutions
-:

```
]# cat ~/0/test <(tac <~/0/test) <(grep 'world' <~/0/test) <(tac <~/0/test)
hello
world
world
hello
world
world
hello
```

So in principle this works,

But I know that "fd/63" error; but to provoke it? By levaving out a space it "works" somehow.

```
]# cat ~/0/test <(tac <~/0/test) <(grep 'world' <~/0/test)<(tac <~/0/test)
hello
world
world
hello
cat: /dev/fd/62/dev/fd/61: Not a directory
```

`/dev/fd/` is file descriptors; the standard way to implement PS.